# Save data from form into 2 models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, model

I'm creating a registration and login app with Django. I get the data using a form and POST.
I want to save the form data into two Django models:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And the Django User model.

**forms.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from .models import *


class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

**Registration View.py**

```
def registerPage(request):
    form = CreateUserForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateUserForm(request.POST)
        form2 = Customer
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            name = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            form2.save(user, name, email)
            messages.success(request, 'Account was created for ' + user)

            return redirect('login')

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'login/register.html', context)
```

Now my question is, how do I save the form data into the user models AND save the data(user, name, email) into the Customers model?

I tried using form2.save(user, name, email) but i get an error message:

*'str' object has no attribute '_meta'*

Thank for any help!

Edit:
I tried the solution of @Moha369, but now I get an error message saying:
*Cannot assign "'test1.2'": "Customer.username" must be a "User" instance*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically its not possible because you are declaring the model previously in meta in the form creation.

But i think the simplest solution might be creating a new object from cleaned data.

```py
user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
name = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
obj = Customer(username = user, name = name, email = email)
obj.save()
form.save()
```

**EDIT** I apologize i missed the part where username is a User object, edited answer:

```py
user = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
name = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
u = form.save()
obj = Customer(username = u, name = name, email = email)
obj.save()
```

What happened here is that `save()` method returns the object we've just saved, so we assigned it to `u` and used it to create the new object.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tired your solution but now i get an error message saying: Cannot assign "'test1.2'": "Customer.username" must be a "User" instance. test1.2 is the user i tried to create. Do you know the solution to this aswell?

Comment: @JEA i apologize for my mistake, edited my answer. Hope it works.

Comment: No problem you are a Hero :3 Thank you so much it works!